# Spring Locale - Cannot read properties files whose size is more than 15kb

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, locale

Currently in my project using Spring Boot 2.5.12 and thymeleaf to render pages.
I have setup Internationalization based on Baeldung guide (https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-internationalization) and currently have somes messages_xx.properties files.
EN: 10kb,
DE: 20kb,
FR: 23kb,
TW: 16kb

I am facing an issue that whenever it try to read the files whose size are larger 16kb, it always fall back to the EN one.
I have tried to duplicate the EN file, rename it to DE and its size is 10kb and yes the system can read the DE file perfectly fine.

Tbh I'm kinda stuck now, if you guys have any suggestions or solutions please let me know, thank you.

Comment: There is nothing file size related in the code. I suspect it has to do with file encoding instead.

Comment: Hi Deinum, thank you for your response, indeed it is file encoding, some files have UTF-16 encoded instead of UTF-8 encoded, that's why some of them cannot be read

Comment: You probably want to unify the encoding to one or the other and set that in your properties `spring.messages.encoding` (default is UTF8).